# Restrict folder templates in Alfresco share to a particular site

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise

I am using Alfresco enterprise 6.2.2

I am trying to create folder structures in Alfresco, and limit those to users of particular site. Is there a way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,You can limit Folder template menu for particular site or for particular group.

You need to extend toolbar.js using share extension approach.

Below link is for your reference. same approach you can take.

https://heshawa.wordpress.com/alfresco-create-from-template-menu-arrange-with-sub-menues/

Ex. Customization for particular group.

```
<extension>
    <modules>
        <module>
            <id>Customize title menu for Collaborations</id>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <customizations>
                ....
            </customizations>
            
            <evaluator type="group.module.evaluator">
                <params>
                    <groups>GROUP_COLLABORATION_MENU,GROUP_COLLABORATION_MANAGERS,GROUP_ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS</groups>
                    <groupRelation>OR</groupRelation>
                </params>
            </evaluator>
            <auto-deploy>true</auto-deploy>
            
        </module>
    </modules>
</extension>
```

Comment: Thanks Sanjay, it says to organize templates in menu bar, what should be done additionally to give access to a particular template to a group / role?

Comment: Check updated answer . Here example is given for site. https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/latest/develop/share-ext-points/surf-extension-modules/